# Java sorting program, getting a confusing output

Tags: java, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // declarations
    int i, z, x, greatest;
    int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 55, 6 };
    int[] copyarray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int zz;
    greatest = array[0];

    for (zz = 0; zz < 5; zz++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            if (array[x] > greatest) {
                greatest = array[x];
            }
        }

        copyarray[zz] = greatest; // this will contain the sorted array
        // part of the nested loop
        for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
            if (greatest == array[z]) {
                array[z] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    // not part of the nested loop
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("sorted array: " + copyarray);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sorted array: [I@1a16869
sorted array: [I@1a16869
sorted array: [I@1a16869
sorted array: [I@1a16869
sorted array: [I@1a16869
```

This is just a basic little program and I'm trying to get the logic right. I can't improve it or make it into a class or method because I'm not even getting the output right.

Comment: you have to print `copyarray[i]`

Comment: Try `System.out.println("sorted array: " + copyarray[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use your own algorithm, i would suggest you try using IDE and debug the code.

If you want to use algorithm that JDK provides, you could use:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Regarding the output, you are trying to print array and array is an object without toString implementation in java. Hence you should change your print statement to :

```
System.out.println("sorted array: "+Arrays.toString(copyarray));//without surrounding for loop to get what its after each step of sorting elements.
```

Or if you want to keep your for loop then you could use index based access to array like:

```
 System.out.print(copyarray[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the reference not the value
use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < copyarray.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println("Value : " + copyarray[i]);
}
```

i would also recommend using `Arrays.sort(array);`

just write

```
private int[] values = { 9,2,5,3,1,7,0 };

  public void printSorted() {
    Arrays.sort(values);
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + values[i]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, none of the answers here are right.

The heart of the problem is that you are not re-initializing the variable `greatest` for each iteration. It is set to `array[0];` in the beginning and it is never changed again. This should go inside the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // declarations
    int i, z, x, greatest;
    int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 55, 6 };
    int[] copyarray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int zz;
    // greatest = array[0]; <---- Don't do it here

    for (zz = 0; zz < 5; zz++) {
        greatest = array[0]; // <--- Initialize greatest here and not before the loop
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            if (array[x] > greatest) {
                greatest = array[x];
            }
        }

        copyarray[zz] = greatest; // this will contain the sorted array
        // part of the nested loop
        for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
            if (greatest == array[z]) {
                array[z] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    // not part of the nested loop
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("sorted array: " + copyarray[i]);
    }
}
```

As a side note, you are printing the array incorrectly, you should use `copyarray[i]` and not `copyarray`.

Whit these two changes, here's the output:

```
sorted array: 55
sorted array: 6
sorted array: 4
sorted array: 3
sorted array: 2
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers! Great feedback! Especially Tunaki! I would have run into the 'greatest' variable misplacement if you hadn't pointed it out! 
Sincere gratitude :) cheers!

Comment: @ShayanNiazi Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer that helped you the most.